# Quantifying the difference between two revisions in a Google Document

Tags: google-docs

Is there any way to quantify the difference between two revisions in a Google Document? (e.g. the number of added/removed/modified characters/words/sentences/lines between two revisions, as we can do with [git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528111/395857) regarding the number of lines changed).

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, Chrome. I tried Googling the question and couldn't find any official help articles on it. I tried going through the Google Documents menu but couldn't find anything.

Comment: This question has being asked twice in the past ([1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72658/), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136821/), [3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149154/) and deleted three times by the Community bot so, for it to be given a fourth opportunity for answering, it needs to have considerably more details included, like what have you done to try to answer it yourself before posting it this fourth time.